# Как получить ответ от кнопки?

Tags: winapi, c++

У меня есть 2 кнопки. Но как отправить в "`LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure...`" инфу о том, что они нажаты?

```
hbut2 = CreateWindowEx(NULL, szBtnClassName, "Âûõîä", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 300, 300, 200, 40, hwnd, NULL, hThisInstance, NULL);
hbut = CreateWindowEx(NULL, szBtnClassName, "Óñòàíîâèòü Lardi Plus", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 50, 300, 200, 40, hwnd, NULL, hThisInstance, NULL);
HRGN rgn = CreateRoundRectRgn(10, 10, 190, 40, 15, 15);
SetWindowRgn(hbut, rgn, TRUE);
SetWindowRgn(hbut2, rgn, TRUE);
// ----------------------
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

Comment: А можно спросить где вы нашли книги про эти методы создания интерфейса Windows?

Comment: В Интернете нарыл просто чей то исходник и вырвал мне нужное

Answer (score 1):

Нужно послать главному окну WM_COMMAND, в параметрах которого передать информацию о кнопке. (Вы, кстати, забыли указать при создании кнопок их идентификаторы).

```
//Simulating a button click (ON_BN_CLICKED).
//This will simulate the IDC_OK button ebing clicked.

WPARAM wParam = BN_CLICKED;
wParam = MAKEWPARAM( IDC_OK, BN_CLICKED );
LPARAM lParam = (LPARAM)GetDlgItem(IDC_OK);
BOOL bval = ::PostMessage(m_hWnd, WM_COMMAND, wParam, lParam);
```

Подробности см. [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо помогло! А как определить какая из них нажата?

Comment: HWND hbut, nbut2; А уменя пишет что IDC_OK неизвесная переменная. Позырил хидер а там IDC_NO есть а IDC_OK нема!!!